# I2C scan returns more devices than connected

Tags: i2c, digital-communications, esp32, imu

I am using an ESP32 WROOM 32D on a self-designed PCB to read from two sensors:
an IMU ([LSM6DSO32](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6dso32.pdf)) and a pressure sensor ([LPS22df](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lps22df.pdf)).

The IMU reads and writes flawlessly, while the pressure sensor hasn't so far.
To see wether the chip works at all, I ran an I2C scanner program, which cycles through all addresses and listens for a response.

The interesting thing is, that this scan returns 3 addresses:

- 0x6A (adress of the IMU)
- 0x5C (adress of the LPS22df)
- 0x7E (unknown)

The bus is only connected to those two sensors and the ESP32 as the Master.
The second interesting observation: The LPS22df has two addresses that can be selected by driving a pin high or low. In my current setup the address shouldn't be 0x5C, it should be 0x5D.

Has anybody a hint or a direction where the third address could come from?

Comment: Can you remove one chip at a time from bus to see when the extra address disappears? I've worked with chips that can use multiple software configurable I2C addresses in addition to the hardware settable addreses. More than once it has happened that some of these software configurable addresses are accidentally enabled and set to some default value after reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private address I2C and [MIPI I3C](https://www.mipi.org/). See you datasheet.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Addresses of the form 0000XXX and 1111XXX are [reserved for various purposes](https://www.i2c-bus.org/addressing/); you should not scan them.